# Unit testing and visibility scope

Tags: .net, unit-testing

Some classes and methods are *internal* in my project. I want to place its unit tests (I use Gallio) in other project (to separate the application code from a unit testing code). But this case the *internal* classes and methods will be invisible for the tests and I can't test them. I don't want to declare them as a *public* for this problem solving only.

How to do it usually in practice?

P.S. Both projects are located in the same solution (MS Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make an assembly a 'Friend' and then it will be able to see the internals:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/0tke9fxk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use the attibute **InternalsVisibleTo**

In your assemblyinfo.cs add

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestAssembly")]
```

Comment: Thank you. @JDunkerley wrote it too.